# Tosca XML Ressource - more than one control found for action "XML node"

Tags: xml, automation, tosca

Context: I'm trying to automatize the comparison between an XML and data Table

XML structure:

```
<mtm>
 <mtmGlItemList>
   <mtmGlItem>
   </mtmGlItem>
   <mtmGlItem>
   </mtmGlItem>
</mtmGlItemList>
</mtm>
```

First step is working, I'm counting the number of lines of my table let's say 2.
I'm buffering this count = 2

Second steps I'm looping on the XML read based on buffer from step 1 with the hope to read the first mtmGlItem and then the second.

I end up with the error message :

> mtmGlItem > More than one control found for action mtmGlitem.

I understand that tosca doesn't know which mtmGlitem to read but I don't see how to get rid of this issue.

Any help super appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to constrain, meaning you need to tell it which item you want to compare. In your case that would be the index. Find more about it here: https://documentation.tricentis.com/en/1200/index.htm#engines_3.0/api/api_tc_lists.htm?Highlight=constrain

Comment: I make it work by doing the following:
1. In the module, add configuration parameter on "mtmGlItem" -> ExplicitName = True
2. In the associated test case, I have replaced "mtmGlItem" by #{Repetition}.